# Decrypting ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor encrypted values in python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails project that has sensitive string type values stored on a remote Postgresql database. I encrypted these strings using the ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html) functions. I have the key I used to encrypt them and trying to find a way to retrieve them from the database and decrypt them in a python script.

I'am open for any suggestions on how to achieve this in any other way using rails and python. And much appreciated for any advice on how to decrypt these values in python.

Thanks,

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

So we managed to solve this with a lot of hit and trial and lot of help from some outdated or similar codes on internet.

#### Versions used of different libraries:

**Rails version**(from which messages were being encrypted): `5.2.x`
**Python version** we are using: `3.8`

We are also using **Django rest framework**(`3.12.2`).

Versions of libraries used in the script(this bit us hard, because some libraries' new versions were not working as expected, didn't dig in much detail as to why):

`pycryptodomex`: `3.9.7`
`cryptography`: `3.3.1`
`rubymarshal`: `1.2.7`

#### Actual encryptor/decryptor

```
# pylint: disable=missing-module-docstring,too-few-public-methods
import base64
import hashlib
import os

from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher
from rubymarshal.reader import loads
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rubymarshal.writer import writes
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

class MyRailsEncryptor():
    """
    This is a class for providing encryption/decryption functionality.
    """
    @classmethod
    def get_encrypted_data(cls, data):
        """
        This method handles encryption algorithm takes in data and return encrypted data
        """
        key = cls.get_key()
        iv = os.urandom(16)
        auth_tag = os.urandom(16)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
        ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(writes(data))
        ciphertext = base64.b64encode(ciphertext)
        iv = base64.b64encode(iv)
        auth_tag = base64.b64encode(auth_tag)

        blob = f'{ciphertext.decode("utf-8")}--{iv.decode("utf-8")}--{auth_tag.decode("utf-8")}' 
        return blob

    @classmethod
    def get_decrypted_data(cls, data):
        """
        This method handles decryption algorithm takes in encrypted_data and return decrypted plain text
        """
        key = cls.get_key()
        ciphertext, iv, auth_tag = data.split("--")
        ciphertext = base64.b64decode(ciphertext)
        iv = base64.b64decode(iv)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
        try:
            decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
        except AssertionError as err:
            return Response({"Assertion Error": err.message_dict}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        plaintext = loads(decrypted_data)
        return plaintext

    @classmethod
    def get_key(cls):
        """
        Returns key generated by Encryption key and Encryption secret using hashlib on rails methodology
        """
        return hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha1', os.getenv("ENCRYPTION_KEY").encode(),
                            os.getenv("ENCRYPTION_SECRET").encode(), 65536, 32)
```

Keys will obviously be synced/provided by the encryption party, this contains a method for encryption as well, though we only need decryption.